# how can update table in with case by postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, common-table-expression

I have been runned success in SQL-Server. Some thing like below.

```
With cte As
(
    SELECT FolderNo,Sort,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(Sort,0) ASC, DateModified ASC) AS RN
    FROM MyTable where ParentNo = 1 AND IsDeleted = false
)
--select * from cte
UPDATE cte SET Sort=RN;
```

But in postgresql it give me an error

*relation "cte" does not exist*

How can I do it in postgresql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update the result of a CTE in Postgres. You need to join the query:

```
update mytable
  set sort = t.rn
from (  
    SELECT FolderNo,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sort nulls first ASC, DateModified ASC) AS RN
    FROM MyTable 
    where ParentNo = 1 
      AND IsDeleted = false
) t
where t.folderno = mytable.folderno
```

This assumes that `folderno` is the primary key of the table (or at least unique)